# Paypal dependencies error with existing project

Tags: android, paypal, gradle

My application is working fine until I added the Paypal dependencies to my application which is `compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.5'`

The error is:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I have tried `multiDexEnabled true` but also no help.

Here's my build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kiwakosan.testing"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':lib')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
//compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.8.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.12.5' //recently added 
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have the PayPal SDK in your lib folder. remove it and it should work.

Comment: May I know which lib folder are you refering to? 'compile project(':lib')' has no PayPal SDK @apmartin1991